# How to use the value in a file as input for a calculation in awk - in bash?

Tags: bash, for-loop, awk, cycle

I'm trying to calculate if the count for each row is more than a certain value, 30% of the total counts.

Within a for cycle, I've obtained the percentage in `awk '$1=($1/100)*30' ${i}_counts > ${i}_percentage-value` and that's a single number, the output only contains that.

How do I make the calculation "value is greater than" for each row of `${i}_counts` against `${i}_percentage-value`?
In other words, how to use the number inside the file as a numerical value for a math operation?

Data:

data.csv (an extract)

```
SampleID    ASV    Count
1000A   ASV_1216    14
1000A   ASV_12580   150
1000A   ASV_12691   260
1000A   ASV_135     434
1000A   ASV_147     79
1000A   ASV_15      287
1000A   ASV_16      361
1000A   ASV_184     8
1000A   ASV_19      42
```

samples-ID-short

```
1000A
1000B
1000C
```

So for each sample ID, there's a lot of ASV, a quantity that may vary a lot like 50 ASV for 1000A, 120 for 1000B and so on. Every ASV_## has a count and my code is for calculating the count total sum, then finding out which is the 30% value for each sample, report which ASV_## is greater than 30%. Ultimately, it should report a 0 for <30% and 1 for >30%.

Here's my code so far:

```
    for i in $(cat samplesID-short)
    do
    grep ${i} data.csv | cut -d , -f3 - > ${i}_count_sample
    grep ${i} data.csv | cut -d , -f2 - > ${i}_ASV
    awk '{ sum += $1; } END { print sum; }' ${i}_count_sample > ${i}_counts
    awk '$1=($1/100)*30' ${i}_counts > ${i}_percentage-value

#I was thinking about replicate the numeric value for the entire column and make the comparison "greater than", but the repetition times depend on the ASV counts for each sample, and they are always different.

    wc -l ${i}_ASV > n
    for (( c=1; c<=n; c++)) ; do echo ${i}_percentage-value ; done

    paste <(sed 's/^[[:blank:]]*//' ${i}_ASV) ${i}_count_sample ${i}_percentage-value > ${i}_tmp; 
    awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"}{if($2 >= $3) print $1}' ${i}_tmp > ${i}_is30;

#How the output should be:

    paste <(sed 's/^[[:blank:]]*//' ${i}_ASV) ${i}_count_sample ${i}_counts ${i}_percentage-value ${i}_is30 > ${i}_summary_nh
    echo -e "ASV_ID\tASV_in_sample\ttotal_ASVs_inSample\ttreshold_for_30%\tASV_over30%" | cat - ${i}_summary_nh > ${i}_summary
    rm ${i}_count_sample ${i}_counts ${i}_percentage-value ${i}_ASV ${i}_summary_nh ${i}_is30
    done &
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would you please try the following:

```
awk -v OFS="\t" '
    NR==FNR {   # this block is executed in the 1st pass only
        if (FNR > 1) sum[$1] += $3
                # accumulate the "count" for each "SampleID"
        next
    }
                # the following block is executed in the 2nd pass only
    FNR > 1 {   # skip the header line
        if ($1 != prev_id) {
                # SampleID has changed. then update the output filename and print the header line
            if (outfile) close(outfile)
                # close previous outfile
            outfile = $1 "_summary"
            print "ASV_ID", "ASV_in_sample", "total_ASVs_inSample", "treshold_for_30%", "ASV_over30%" >> outfile
            prev_id = $1
        }
        mark = ($3 > sum[$1] * 0.3) ? 1 : 0
                # set the mark to "1" if the "Count" exceeds 30% of sum
        print $2, $3, sum[$1], sum[$1] * 0.3, mark >> outfile
                # append the line to the summary file
    }
' data.csv data.csv
```

data.csv:

```
SampleID    ASV    Count
1000A   ASV_1216    14
1000A   ASV_12580   150
1000A   ASV_12691   260
1000A   ASV_135     434
1000A   ASV_147     79
1000A   ASV_15      287
1000A   ASV_16      361
1000A   ASV_184     8
1000A   ASV_19      42
1000B   ASV_1       90
1000B   ASV_2       90
1000B   ASV_3       20
1000C   ASV_4       100
1000C   ASV_5       10
1000C   ASV_6       10
```

In the following output examples, the last field `ASV_over30%` indicates `1` if the count exceeds 30% of the sum value.

1000A_summary:

```
ASV_ID  ASV_in_sample   total_ASVs_inSample     treshold_for_30%        ASV_over30%
ASV_1216        14      1635    490.5   0
ASV_12580       150     1635    490.5   0
ASV_12691       260     1635    490.5   0
ASV_135 434     1635    490.5   0
ASV_147 79      1635    490.5   0
ASV_15  287     1635    490.5   0
ASV_16  361     1635    490.5   0
ASV_184 8       1635    490.5   0
ASV_19  42      1635    490.5   0
```

1000B_summary:

```
ASV_ID  ASV_in_sample   total_ASVs_inSample     treshold_for_30%        ASV_over30%
ASV_1   90      200     60      1
ASV_2   90      200     60      1
ASV_3   20      200     60      0
```

1000C_summary:

```
ASV_ID  ASV_in_sample   total_ASVs_inSample     treshold_for_30%        ASV_over30%
ASV_4   100     120     36      1
ASV_5   10      120     36      0
ASV_6   10      120     36      0
```

**[Explanations]**

When calculating the average of the input data, we need to go through until
the end of the data. If we want to print out the input record and the average
value (or other information based on the average) at the same time, we need to
use a trick:

- To store the whole input records in memory.
- To read the input data twice.

As `awk` is suitable for reading multiple files changing the proceduce
depending the order of files, I have picked the 2nd method.

- The condition `NR==FNR` returns `TRUE` while reading the 1st file only.
  We calculate the sum of `count` field within this block as a 1st pass.
- The `next` statement at the end of the block skips the following codes.
- If the 1st file is done, the script reads the 2nd file which is
  same as the 1st file, of course.
- While reading the 2nd file, the condition `NR==FNR` no longer returns
  `TRUE` and the 1st block is skipped.
- The 2nd block reads the input file again, opening a file to print the
  output, reading the input data line by line, and adding information
  such as average value obtained in the 1st pass.

Comment: Thank you so much, it works! But it stops when a sample has many ASV, for example it has stopped with 89 ASV saying "awk: 1004A_summary makes too many open files". Since I have also samples with more than 500 ASVs, how can I overcome this limitation?

Comment: Probably it's because of the size of the real "data.csv" I use, 17MB.

Comment: @camcecc10 thank you for the feedback. To tell the truth I did not imagine you have so many sample-IDs :). I have updated my code to close previous files to avoid the error. Would you please try it? BTW I'm assuming the `sampleID` in `data.csv` is sorted as a block, not located randomly. Otherwise the header line in the *_summary file is put multiple times. Is my assumption correct? BR.

Comment: Your assumption is correct and the addition to the code worked perfectly! Thank you so much, I hope one day I'll be able to code as you do, you saved me!

Comment: Sorry if I bother you again, but could you explain shortly how it uses the two inputs?

Comment: @camcecc10 thank you for the feedback. Good to know it works. I've added some explanations in my answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can filter on a column based on a value e.g

```
$ awk '$3>300' data.csv
SampleID    ASV    Count
1000A   ASV_135     434
1000A   ASV_16      361
```

You can use >= for greater than or equal to.

It looks like your script is overcomplicating matters.

Comment: I'm a beginner, so you're probably right about complicating. But the 30% value is always different because of the ASV count, is not the same for every sample. i calculate the 30% for each sample, then I want to use that value as the 300 you set up in the example.

Comment: You can use something like: `awk 'NR>1{A[$1]+=$3;I[$1]++}END{for(i in A) if (A[i]) print i,A[i]*.3}' data.csv` to get the 30% mark and then loop around.

Answer (score 1):

this should work

```
$ awk 'NR==1 || $3>$1*3/10' file

SampleID    ASV    Count
1000A   ASV_135     434
1000A   ASV_16      361
```

or, with the indicator column

```
$ awk 'NR==1{print $0, "Ind"} NR>1{print $0, ($3>$1*3/10)}' file | column -t

SampleID  ASV        Count  Ind
1000A     ASV_1216   14     0
1000A     ASV_12580  150    0
1000A     ASV_12691  260    0
1000A     ASV_135    434    1
1000A     ASV_147    79     0
1000A     ASV_15     287    0
1000A     ASV_16     361    1
1000A     ASV_184    8      0
1000A     ASV_19     42     0
```